Wittgenstein and the possibility of expressing a logical form
Why did Wittgenstein in TLP considered the "logic of facts" and a logical form inexpressible?
If I'm not mistaken, he himself a lot of times was trying to describe a logical form in his work.
Did he simply mean that in some proposition F(x) itself cannot be shown its logical form (but it can be shown by additional means)?
But isn't the logical form is already contained in the notation of F(x)?
What does even mean to express those things?
P.S. I don't have Wittgenstein's text on my hands now, so please try to understand my question even though it may be very vague.

Not "inexpressible". Wittgenstein distinguishes two different forms of "expression", "what can be shown cannot be said", see SEP, Sense and Nonsense:"The propositions of logic... do not picture anything and do not, therefore, have sense... what cannot be formulated in sayable (sensical) propositions can only be shown. This applies, for example, to the logical form of the world, the pictorial form, etc., which show themselves in the form of (contingent) propositions, in the symbolism, and in logical propositions."

"logical form" is what any significant [vs nonsensical] sentence must have in common with reality to represent it. If significant (i.e. if we can understand its sense), we can judge if the sentence is true or false. See 4.12: "Propositions can represent the whole of reality, but they cannot represent what they must have in common with reality in order to be able to represent it—logical form."

@MauroALLEGRANZA can we represent a logical form of one proposition by the means of another one?

There is no "meta-theory" in Tractatus.

@ЕгорГалыкин - This is exactly Russell's question in his original introduction. It's not just so that the TLP has no meta-theory, W seems to be denying that a meta-theory would be possible (or make sense to develop). That seems to be one of the points of the saying/showing distinction.

See P.T. Geach, Saying and Showing in Frege and Wittgenstein in Essays on Wittgenstein in Honour of G.H. von Wright (J. Hintikka editor, Amsterdam, 1976).
According to Geach, we can understand what the Tractatus holds about saying and showing reading what Frege writes about the saying/showing distinction.
Geach writes that "a great deal of the Tractatus is best
understood as a refashioning of Frege's function-argument analysis in order to remove [from it the] mistaken treatment of sentences as complex names."
Frege fundamental distinction between Function and Object is that between two mutually incompatible categories; an object is "saturated" while a function is not and this explain why we can combine the two producing a meaningful statement (and why the f(f) expression is meaningless; see Tractatus 3.333).
Fregean notion of an entity’s "category", later rewritten by Russell in the theory of logical types, has been inherited by Wittgenstein: the possibility of combining objects with functions (and, in general, relations) to form states of affairs is an intrinsic feature of an object: its logical form:

2.01 A state of affairs is a combination of objects (entities, things).


2.011–2.012 It is essential to things that they should be possible constituents of states of affairs.
In logic nothing is accidental: if a thing can occur in a state of affairs, the possibility of the state of affairs must be written into the thing itself.


2.0141 The possibility of its occurring in states of affairs is the form of an object.

P.Geach: "Frege already held that there are logical category-distinctions which will clearly show themselves in a well-constructed formalized language, but which cannot properly be asserted in language."
See Terence Parsons, Why Frege Should Not Have Said The Concept Horse is Not a Concept (1986):

Frege held various views about language and its relation to non-linguistic things. These views led him to the paradoxical-sounding conclusion that "the concept horse is not a concept".

In conclusion, if logical form is the pre-requisite for representation (it is the possibility that a sentence to meaningfully express a fact) it cannot be represented.
In the Tractatus we find examples of logical formulas: see e.g. 3.333 discussing the "theory of types", etc.
So, maybe, the issue is that according to W, we cannot "describe" the logical form of a statement (the "pictured" fact) because in order to do this we have to use a significant proposition (the "picturing" fact) whose logical form must be the same as the first one, and thus we are running in a circle.
If so, the only way to understand logical form is by way of a sort of "intuition" that we cannot analyse further. We cannot "say" it, but we can only "show" it:

3.332: No proposition can make a statement about itself,
because a propositional sign cannot be contained in
itself (that is the whole of the ‘theory of types’).


Note: this idea is so fundamental for W that we will find it once again into PI; see §96-97:

Thought, language, now appear to us as the unique correlate, picture, of the world. [...] Its essence, logic, presents
an order, in fact the a priori order of the world: that is, the order of possibilities, which must be common to both world and thought.


Note: The reference to PI 96-97 seems misleading in this context. In PI 96-97 W is severely criticizing the earlier TLP views. Whether or not he is still holding on to some form of the saying/showing distinction -- in regards to logical form -- is at least very debatable; I would argue, he is not. (The TLP view would be condemned as "language idling", I think.)

Consider a proposition, "a R b", where 'a' and 'b' are supposed to refer to simple objects and 'R' is a phrase to express a relation between two objects.
This proposition says that the two objects, a and b, stand in the relation R to each other; it says that a R b. (E.g. "The leopard is behind the zebu"). The proposition shows that symbol 'a' is to the left of symbol 'b' . We can see this - with our eyes - there is no special, mysterious kind of intuition involved in this. It's part of the logical form of this proposition that symbol 'a' is to the left of 'b'; by convention we might also want 'R' to be in the middle, or use some other convention (like "R(a, b)"). So, the whole logical form then simply is itself a (complex) fact, the fact that 'a' is to the left of 'b' and that 'R' is the relation-word linking them.

3.1432 Instead of, 'The complex sign "aRb" says that a stands to b in the relation R', we ought to put, 'That "a" stands to "b" in a certain relation says that "aRb".'

The proposition 'a R b' "shows what it says" (4.461), what it says is, that a R b, that the object referred to by 'a' stands in some relation 'R' (understood as 'x R y' is to be understood) to the object referred to by 'b'. Note that when we express 'what it says', we again exhibit the same logical form (we have to repeat the words in the same order). We cannot, as it were, escape from having to repeat the same symbols in the same (in principle arbitrary, but previously determined) order.
So, we can easily talk about, refer to or describe (in a vague sense of the word 'describe') the logical form of particular, given propositions. Wittgenstein does not deny this. The logical form of facts is not "inexpressible". In fact, logical tautologies are the logical forms of propositions. A tautology doesn't say anything (doesn't represent or picture any state of affairs in the world), but exhibits the logical form (common to all statements using the particular connectives as used in that tautology). (See in particular 6.12 and following.)
Wittgenstein defines "logical form" in

2.18 What any picture, of whatever form, must have in common with reality, in order to be able to depict it —- correctly or incorrectly —- in any way at all, is logical form, i.e. the form of reality.

A core statement about saying/showing then is

4.021 A proposition is a picture of reality (...)
4.022 A proposition shows its sense. [Sinn] A proposition shows how things stand if it is true. And it says that they do so stand. (...)

What Wittgenstein denies is that any picture (including propositions which he sees as essentially pictures mirroring possible states of affairs) can depict itself or that any picture could depict it's way of depicting what it depicts. In other words, absolute or unmediated, direct self-reference is impossible. Similarly, no proposition can itself describe or directly depict how it represents the state of affairs that it (possibly) represents. No proposition can describe it's own sense, or it's own truth-conditions, it's own relation to "the world".
From this to the statement that "there are" facts that can only be shown and not expressed or said, is still an extra step.

6.522  There is indeed the inexpressible. This shows itself; it is the mystical.

As far as I understand this, this step is based on the assumption that there are "elementary" propositions. (This is probably the weakest part of the TLP. In the Philosophical Investigations he severly critizes this assumption, together with the related assumptions about names and "simple names", and abandons it.)
The above interpretation is by and large the same as the interpretation given by Guillame Decauwert, in Saying and Showing: The Single Solution of All the 'Problems of Philosophy' according to Wittgenstein's Tractatus (2013). This article is one of the very few (that I know) that tries to come to a formal characterization of the saying/showing distinction in the TLP by doing a careful, comprehensive close reading of the text, trying to give a coherent account of the various aspects of that distinction, and in particular also of Wittgenstein's bold claim that all philosophical problems are solvable by applying it.
In some form the saying/showing distinction still seems to be in play in Wittgenstein's later philosophy. Martin Pulido, in The Place of Saying and Showing in Wittgenstein's Tractatus and Some Later Works (2009), argues that it for instance still shows up in Wittgenstein's discussion of 'aspect-blindness' (PI 211–214). According to him it is also in play in Wittgenstein's later remarks about mathematics and in On Certainty (his latest notes, criticizing Moore's unsatisfactory refutation of solipsism). However, Pulido is extremely vague about exactly what the similarity between the earlier and later work consists in, so, in my opinion, the question to what extent the saying/showing distinction as posited in the TLP is still present in the later work, is very much an open question. It's interesting to look for this, however. Especially also, because there is a link to the "meaning as use" approach in PI (the pragmatic embedding of language), which is foreshadowed in the TLP. See, for instance (first two italics are mine, last one is in the text):

3.326 In order to recognize a symbol by its sign we must observe how it is used with a sense. A sign does not determine a logical form unless it is taken together with its logico- syntactical employment. If a sign is useless it is meaningless. (...)

In the PI Wittgenstein no longer talks of the "logical form" of propositions, or the "logical syntax", but he does talk of the "grammar" -- and about using the grammar of how we talk in actual, everyday language to clarify (and resolve) philosophical muddles. "Grammar" in this case has a similar function as "logical form" used to have (in the TLP). It's a wider concept than simply linguistic syntax. It's never completely made clear what Wittgenstein means by it, but perhaps we can say that it is the pragmatic embedding of our language games. And perhaps this embedding can also never be completely grasped (described) in language (?) But we can show it (that is, a relevant part of this 'grammar'), by presenting exemplary language games that exhibit it.

(Title: Wittgenstein and the possibility of expressing a logical form)
TLP was written 100 years ago. At the time, mathematical logic and philosophy were in a honeymoon state due to the influence of Frege and Russell, but I think things have calmed down quite a bit now. You cannot go beyond TLP just by reading TLP. You must know the scientific achievements of the past 100 years that Wittgenstein did not know about.
I think the most important message in TLP is that it wants readers to create "my language" in which "The limits of my language mean the limits of my world." Since "my language" comes before "my world," it asserts idealism. Also, dualistic (= Copenhagen interpretation) quantum mechanics is something that Wittgenstein did not know about 100 years ago, but is now common knowledge. This means that if we generalize quantum mechanics mathematically (i.e., idealize, verbalize), we can create a language for the world of dualistic idealism. Let's call this language QL (= quantum language). I am convinced that QL is Wittgenstein's "my language." The descriptive power of quantum language is astounding, and it includes quantum mechanics, logic, and statistics, meaning that quantum language is another scientific language that is separate from physics (realism).　Also, note that the perfection of dualistic idealism was the ultimate goal of the history of Western philosophy.
I've written a lot above, but the following diagram says it all.

For more details, see https://ishikawa.math.keio.ac.jp/indexe.html
